# Avoid bevel in holes of ExtrudeGeometry

Tags: three.js

I need to create a shape (a simple rectangle) with a hole in it and extrude it using a bevel.
The bevel should be on the "outer" edges of the shape but not in the hole.

I'm trying with this code:

```
      var r = 0.05;
      var w = 4;
      var l = 4;

      var shape = new THREE.Shape();
      shape.moveTo(-w + r, -l);
      shape.absarc(-w + r, -l + r, r, -Math.PI / 2, Math.PI, true);
      shape.lineTo(-w, l - r);
      shape.absarc(-w + r, l - r, r, Math.PI, Math.PI / 2, true);
      shape.lineTo(w - r, l);
      shape.absarc(w - r, l - r, r, Math.PI / 2, 0, true);
      shape.lineTo(w, -l + r);
      shape.absarc(w - r, -l + r, r, 0, -Math.PI / 2, true);

      const hole = new THREE.Path();
      hole.moveTo(1, 1);
      hole.lineTo(1, 2);
      hole.lineTo(2, 2);
      hole.lineTo(2, 1);
      hole.lineTo(1, 1);

      shape.holes = [hole];

      let geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(shape, { depth: 2, bevelEnabled: false });
```

I'm able to enable/disable the bevel in all the shape,
but I need to exclude the bevel in the hole.

[image]

Thanks a lot